# Amazon S3 how to list files in a “folder”

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload, aws-sdk

I set the key of files in Amazon S3 to be folder\filename. Is there a way to get all the files under a "folder" (search files by regex)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You tagged your question with `aws-sdk` but did not mention a language, so I'll use Python in this answer.

The [`list_objects_v2()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2) command accepts a `Prefix`:

```
response = client.list_objects_v2(
    Bucket='string',
    Delimiter='string',
    EncodingType='url',
    MaxKeys=123,
    Prefix='string',
    ContinuationToken='string',
    FetchOwner=True|False,
    StartAfter='string',
    RequestPayer='requester'
)
```

If you set `Prefix='folder/'`, then it will return objects within that folder.

However, it is *not* possible to use a Regex expression. Your program will need to filter the return list to meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks for this. But this doesn't solve the problem for me because it still shows the files of the *subfolders*. Anyway to tweak your response to do that?

Comment: @GunithD Please create a new Question rather than asking via a comment on an old question.

Answer (score 2):

I hope provided link will answer your question.

[AWS S3 object listing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30726079/aws-s3-object-listing)

You can also get list of objects by using aws-cli

Type following command in terminal

> > aws s3 ls bucketName/folderName/

Here '/' is necessary at the end of folder name, else you will get only folder name in result.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the **list of files in a SUBFOLDER that is present across folders in a S3 bucket**, we can do it using list_objects API. Say, you need all files in **abc** subfolder of bucket **test** having following files:

```
folderA/abc/fileabcX
folderA/def/filedefX
folderB/abc/fileabcY
folderB/def/filedefY
folderC/abc/fileabcZ
folderC/def/filedefZ
folderC/xyz/filexyzZ
```

In Python, we can do it by calling **list_objects_v2 API twice**, where you **get the folder the first time** using empty prefix and / delimiter and using "CommonPrefixes" in the output. Then, **call list_objects_v2 again with your subfolder as part of the prefix** with the folder name that you get in the first call:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('s3')
objs = client.list_objects_v2(Bucket="test", Prefix='', Delimiter='/')
for prefix in objs.get('CommonPrefixes')
    folder = prefix.get('Prefix')
    resp = client.list_objects_v2(
        Bucket="test",
        Prefix=folder + 'abc/',
    )
    if resp.get('Contents') is not None:
        for obj in resp.get('Contents'):
            print(obj.get('Key'))
```

Output:

```
fileabcX
fileabcY
fileabcZ
```