# Why does listing objects in an S3 bucket's folder using AWS SDK for JavaScript returns empty Contents array but KeyCount greater than one?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a bucket in S3 called **myBucketName**. It has one folder called **myFolderName** and is containing one file **myFile**.

I try to list the objects in the folder like so:

```
s3.listObjectsV2({       
  Bucket: 'myBucketName',
  Delimiter: "/",
  Prefix: 'myFolderName',
})
```

With the response

```
{
  IsTruncated: false,
  Contents: [],    
  Name: 'myBucketName',
  Prefix: 'myFolderName',
  Delimiter: '/',
  MaxKeys: 1000,
  CommonPrefixes: [ { Prefix: 'myFolderName/' } ],
  KeyCount: 1 
}
```

How come the `Contents` array is empty even though `KeyCount` is 1? I would have expected to contain one item with Key == 'myFolderName/myFile'

What should I do to get the desired result, i.e. a list of the objects in the folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS S3 object listing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30726079/aws-s3-object-listing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Prefix: 'myFolderName/'` (with the forward slash `/`) when listing the objects. It's telling you there is only one "object" (a folder) in the folder you're asking about.

Comment: Using `Prefix: 'myFolderName/'` will include the folder itself in the `Contents` array. Is that intended?

Comment: Yeah, that's generally the way the API works. There's more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30726079/aws-s3-object-listing. This question is actually probably a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Just to add on this, removing any preceding '/' also works. For my case I had '/myFolderName/output', Removing the first '/' and adding the trailing one worked. Thanks!